# How does the linker know where to find a dll file

Tags: c++, dll, lib

I am working with Visual Studio and I am trying to get into dlls. I'm wondering how the linker knows where to find a DLL just from the lib file alone.
I specify the lib file and its location in the project settings but where isthe location of the associated dll file specified?
Or maybe i don't understand the topic correctly.

Comment: The linker does not use the .dll at all in Visual Studio with the microsoft compiler when compiling native c++. The OS will need to find the dll when you go to execute your program.

Comment: It doesn't know.  The DLL project generates an *import library*, a .lib file, that's the one you need to link.  It is a small file that records the name of the DLL, the exported name or number of an exported function (keeps the loader happy) and the programmatic identifier of the function (keeps the linker happy).  It is up to you to ensure that the DLL can be found at runtime when you start the program that uses the DLL.  Automatic if both projects are in the same solution, usually requires xcopy in a post-build event if they are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Standard Search Order for Desktop Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications) from the Microsoft [Dll Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) documentation:

> If **SafeDllSearchMode** is enabled, the search order is as follows:
>
> 1. The directory from which the application loaded.
> 2. The system directory. Use the [GetSystemDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemdirectorya) function to get the path of this directory.
> 3. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
> 4. The Windows directory. Use the [GetWindowsDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getwindowsdirectorya) function to get the path of this directory.
> 5. The current directory.
> 6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the **App Paths** registry key. The **App Paths** key is not used when computing the DLL search path.

> If **SafeDllSearchMode** is disabled, the search order is as follows:
>
> 1. The directory from which the application loaded.
> 2. The current directory.
> 3. The system directory. Use the [GetSystemDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemdirectorya) function to get the path of this directory.
> 4. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
> 5. The Windows directory. Use the [GetWindowsDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getwindowsdirectorya) function to get the path of this directory.
> 6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the **App Paths** registry key. The **App Paths** key is not used when computing the DLL search path.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. You might as well written the answer yourself there!

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question perfectly.